# How do I toggle a class for only one reused (but not repeated) element in Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs

I have a menu that is used in a couple different places on the same page, though it is NOT ng-repeated. The menu is triggered by toggling the class "open" on button click. My current solution toggles both menus, but I need to toggle just the closest menu. In jQuery, I would do this using $(this).closest(".wrapper").toggle("open"); I'm effectively looking for that equivalent.

I also need to be able to close the menu when clicking outside of it. So something similar to this in jQuery: $("html").click(function() { $(".wrapper").removeClass("open"); });

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="fooApp" ng-controller="fooController">
  <p>foobar</p>
  <div class="wrapper" ng-class="{'open': isActive}">
    <button class="toggle" ng-click="activeButton();">Toggle 1</button>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>foobar</p>
  <div class="wrapper" ng-class="{'open': isActive}">
    <button class="toggle" ng-click="activeButton();">Toggle 2</button>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>foobar</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.open .list {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('fooApp', [])
  .controller("fooController", function($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = false;
    $scope.activeButton = function() {
      $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Since they look identical in your example, you should consider making them components.  Then everything will be contained inside its own scope and they would each have their own isActive variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use two variables: section1Active, section2Active. That way you can have two different ng-classes.

Then you can either write two functions (activeButton1(), activeButton2()) to toggle these new variables or pass a parameter to the activeButton function. Hope that helps!

```
$scope.activeButton1 = function() {
  $scope.isActive1 = !$scope.isActive1;
}

$scope.activeButton2 = function() {
  $scope.isActive2 = !$scope.isActive2;
}
```

This should work for your situation, but its not the most elegant.